# Use JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY without specifying @JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to use `@JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` without needing to specify the subtypes using `@JsonSubtypes`?

The use case is that I'm wanting to create common base classes, which has varying bodies that are declared in other projects.

**Common base class, which contains common fields and the body**

```
public class ApiModel<T extends ApiBodyModel> {

    private String modelType;
    private String version;
    private T body;

... getters / setters

}
```

**The abstract body model, which has further shared context within.**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "modelType")
//@JsonTypeIdResolver(InheritanceTypeIdResolver.class)
public abstract class ApiBodyModel<T extends ApiBodyModel<T>> {

    @JsonProperty
    private ApiContextModel context;

    public T withContext(ApiContextModel context) {
        this.context = context;
        return (T) this;
    }

... getters / setters

}
```

One solution which allowed me to drop the use of `@JsonSubTypes` was to use Reflection to get all subtypes of the abstract `ApiBodyModel`, detailed at https://gist.github.com/root-talis/36355f227ff5bb7a057ff7ad842d37a3, but it still required the classname to be declared within the body, instead of one level up.

Examples found for using `@JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` had `JsonSubTypes` declared, but I want to avoid this as the abstract class will be in a common project.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by having the top level class use the InheritanceTypeIdResolver

**Common base class, which contains common fields and the body**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CUSTOM, property = "modelType", visible = true)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(InheritanceTypeIdResolver.class)
public abstract class ApiModel<T extends ApiBodyModel> {

    private String modelType;
    private String version;

    public abstract T getBody();

    public abstract void setBody(T body);

}
```

**The abstract body model, which has further shared context within.**

```
public abstract class ApiBodyModel {

    private ApiContextModel context;

}
```

**Concrete base class implementation**

```
public class ConcreteModel extends ApiModel<ConcreteBody> {

    public static final String MODEL_TYPE = "concreteModel";

    private ConcreteBody body;

    public ConcreteModel(
        String version,
        ConcreteBody body) {
        super(MODEL_TYPE, version);
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

**Concrete body implementation**

```
public class ConcreteBody extends ApiBodyModel {

    private String source;

    public ConcreteBody(ApiContextModel context, String source) {
        super(context);
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```